# How do I convert a date to Shamsi/Persian format in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I want to convert date to Shamsi/Persian format, but it did not work well. My code:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR('10-JUN-18', 'dd-mm-yy','nls_calendar=persian') 
FROM dual;
```

I want it be like this: `20-03-97`

Answer (score 5):

`TO_CHAR( date_value, format_model, nls_parameters )` takes a `DATE` data type as the first argument.

`'10-JUN-18'` is not a `DATE` data type; it is a string literal (that just happens to look like a date). Oracle will try to perform an implicit conversion from a string to a date but this implicit conversion is failing (and it is bad practice to rely on implicit conversions).

If you use a `DATE` literal then your code works:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE '2018-06-10', 'dd-mm-yy','nls_calendar=persian') AS dt
FROM   DUAL;
```

> | DT |
> | --- |
> | 20-03-97 |

Or, you can explicitly convert the string literal to a date and then convert it back:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_DATE('10-JUN-18', 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'),
         'dd-mm-yy',
         'nls_calendar=persian'
       ) AS dt
FROM   DUAL;
```

> | DT |
> | --- |
> | 20-03-97 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1badf62c6764f98b8cfdda6935a16853)*

Comment: OMG! thank you so much about your explanation, I did not know that